# When using App Themes, how best to handle both Mobile & Desktop CSS detection

Tags: asp.net, css, mobile, themes, app-themes

I currently have a web application that uses Themes to skin it either as SkinA or SkinB. Until now, this has been a web application that has not focused on mobile devices in any way, so the site.css file (within both Theme folders) has targeted normal desktop devices.

However, without changing any of the web form aspx files throughout the project, I now need to create a mobile version of this site.css file (for both Themes) that will alter the layout so as it looks a little bit cleaner when viewed on mobile devices.

I found the following snippets in an article that sounds fairly logical, however, due to Themes folders being used (and from the little I understand about themes, I think all CSS files get included automatically), I'm not sure how I would accomplish this.

Extract from: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/03/how-to-build-a-mobile-website/#mobile-stylesheets

First, define two stylesheets: screen.css with everything for normal browsers and antiscreen.css to overwrite any styles that you don’t want on mobile devices. Tie these two stylesheets together in another stylesheet core.css:

```
@import url("screen.css");
@import url("antiscreen.css") handheld;
@import url("antiscreen.css") only screen and (max-device-width:480px);
```

Finally, define another stylesheet handheld.css with additional styling for mobile browsers and link them on the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="handheld.css" media="handheld, only screen and (max-device-width:480px)"/>
```

Or perhaps there is a better way of accomplishing this, whilst retaining the use of Themes?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this in a project I'm doing at the moment.

One way you can do this is to use Modernizr.

It's a javascript library you can get at modernizr.com.

It will test the destination browser, and if it supports touch events, it will add a style of "touch" to the  element of your webpage. Generally, if Modernizr does this, it's either a tablet or a phone. Then you prefix each style your phone/tablet css with ".touch".

Couple this with media queries, and you should be able to handle most (probably not all) devices out there.